# How to get all elements within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get all the elements inside a div except some specific div
For eg if the structure is as follows

```
<div id="abc">
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="pqr">
        patil</div>
    <div class="pqr">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="pqr">
        rocky</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
    <div class="pqr">
        sfs</div>
    <div class="def">
        sagar patil</div>
```

Now suppose I want the html structure of main div  i.e. div abc but without the content of div pqr i.e. I want all the stuff inside div abc but without div pqr

Comment: Would you post some code of what you have tried so far? It would also help to explain how the result of your code was not as you expected or needed.

Answer (score 7):

Use `:not()`.

```
$("#abc div:not(.pqr)")
```

Or even broader

```
$("#abc :not(.pqr)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the :not filter, or for more readable constructs, [jQuery .not](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("#abc div").not(".pqr, .someOtherClass");
```

That way it's more readable and you can easily include other selectors you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't `var someArray = $('#ID_OF_DIV').children()`

or

`$('#ID_OF_DIV').children().each();`

work in this case? Depending on the conditions (which you haven't told us)